# Is there an algorithm that does scattered points grouping/analysis by attributes

Tags: qgis

Say I have 1000 points of species data scattered within working canvas, where I'd like to get polygons of their potential habitats. For now I'm using "convex hull" by species' name. It kinda does the job but not so pretty.

The process I used is from convex hull -> buffer by a distance -> dissolve by attribute.

The problem here, I mean the term "not pretty" is that those polygons overlapped and looks like bunches of bubbles stacked on top of each other.

For better description. Here's an image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiJwS.jpg

Could there be a better function/algorithm to accomplish the given task?

I'm familiar with Python a PyQGIS solution is desired, but any approach that I can implement by code is also acceptable (or any keyword I could find online that might help).

Comment: Have you tried concave hull?

Comment: I've actually tested out concave full/ convex hull, both generates similar outputs, just doesn't look nice enough. What I want is an approximate boundary by it's clustering if I'm not clear enough. Thank you

Comment: Try Convex hull then smooth

Comment: It is unclear what you want